# how to extract network of city routes from city blocks shapefile?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, network

I have a shapefile which contains urban blocks. So, I am going to extract network shapefile of city routes and calculate total length of network arcs. I am using ArcGIS 10 for this work. Are there any tools for this work?

My idea is to use ArcMap tools that can process city blocks and draw routes arc in gap between block parcels of cities!!

If the question is unclear please tell me to describe more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a Cartography tool to do this called **[Collapse Dual Lines To Centerline](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00700000000t000000)**.

However, it requires you to have an Advanced level license of ArcGIS for Desktop so may or may not be suitable for you.